# Is the Atharvaveda mentioned in the Samaveda?

Tags: vedas, mantras, atharva-veda, sama-veda

I found a mantra on a site which is from the Samaveda.(I don't know where it is in the Samaveda).

> दोषो आगाद्बृहद्गाय द्युमद्गामन्नाथर्वण । स्तुहि देवँ सवितारम्॥

Is this mantra mentioned in the Samaveda? Is the Atharvaveda really mentioned in this mantra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the verse/hymn is present in [Sāmaveda, Kauthuma śākhā](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/1_veda/1_sam/samavedu.htm). According to [this translation](https://books.google.com/books?id=SztmDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT59#v=onepage&q&f=false) it refers to Atharvaveda brāhmaṇas.

> sāmaveda saṃhitā
>
> kauthuma śākhā
>
> aindra kāṇḍam
>
> dvitīya prapāṭhakaḥ . dvitīyo 'rdhaḥ
>
> 1 2 2 0901a īṅkhayantīrapasyuva indraṃ jātamupāsate . 
>   1 2 2 0901c vanvānāsaḥ suvīryam .. 175 
>   1 2 2 0902a na ki devā inīmasi na kyā yopayāmasi .
>   1 2 2 0902c mantraśrutyaṃ carāmasi .. 176
>   1 2 2 0903a **doṣo āgādbṛhadgāya dyumadgāmannātharvaṇa** .
>   1 2 2 0903c **stuhi devaṃ savitāram** .. 177